# How to spec input power of step down converter

Tags: power-supply, current, step-down

I want to know how to spec a step-down converter that I am going to use for a project.

The output voltage of the step down is 12V DC and the max current output is 2.5A (the load pulls about 2A). The input voltage range for this step down is between 5-40V DC. My input voltage is 24V DC.

My question is therefore does my input power supply to the step down must have a current that is greater than 2A or can I use a power supply that can supply a current lower than 2A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a *switching* converter, with that range, the law of power conservation requires that the input power is equal to the output power plus conversion losses.

So you have on the output 12V, 2.5A total 30W. On the input side you'll need 30W plus losses. Assuming a default 80% efficiency you'll need about 38W on the input.

So about 1.6A at 24V, Ohm's law tell you for other values

Comment: I see that makes sense.